# Print Joda-Time Interval

Tags: java, jodatime, intervals

Does anybody know how to print a readable Joda-Time Interval? I tried to search for it but all I find is how to print periods. But I really need Interval.

I construct it something like this:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(bDT, eDT);
```

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? Samples would really help.

Comment: I need to log it and do not care in what format as long as I can understand it.

Comment: So use a `DateTimeFormatter` and format `interval.getStart()` and `interval.getEnd()`.

Comment: I guess if there is no way to just print interval

Comment: Well if you just call toString() it's readable, but I assumed you wanted something different...

Comment: This one is good, if you want to post as answer ill accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `toString()` - `Interval` (or rather `AbstractInterval`) overrides `toString` with a readable format. For example:

```
Instant start = new Instant(0L);
Instant end = new Instant(1390596587000L);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
System.out.println(interval); // Implicitly calls toString()
```

Output (on my box):

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/2014-01-24T20:49:47.000Z
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked perfect for me, prints something like this 1800-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:50:36/2014-01-24T14:40:33.000-06:00